# Unix Shell comnand Pattern to list files expect any one file from pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I have following command to list all files from **cat1** to **cat5**

```
#ls cat[1-5]
```

What modifications do I need to make in above command to list all files except **cat3**

Output should be **cat1 cat2 cat4 cat5**

Also I m trying to list files from cat1 to cat10 with `ls cat[1-10]` but its only showing **cat1** in output

Answer (score 2):

This way you can exclude any list of character:

```
ls cat[^3]
```

Comment: only cat1,cat2,cat4,cat5 are listed, but the other files were not listed with the use of this command.

Comment: yes because no other file start with "cat" in your folder

Comment: I am trying ls cat[1-10] but its only showing cat1 why is it

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | sed -e 's/\<cat3\>//g'
```

This command sequence can produce the result. where cat3 is a filename.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways this can be done.

1. ls cat[1245]
2. ls cat[1-5] | grep -v cat3

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
printf "%s\n" cat{1,2,4,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using regular expressions. So `cat[1-10]` means: all files named cat0 and cat1, since you specify only these two characters inside the brackets (regex does not know numbers, only characters and character ranges).

In order to display everything from 0 to 99999..., you can do the following:

```
# ls cat[0-9]*
```

For more regular expressions in bash you can check some docs:
http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_04_01.html